# Resolving paths in Twig

Tags: theming, 8, uri

I would like to print the content from a file (`/themes/custom/mytheme/misc/info.txt`) into the HTML markup using Twig.

Steps already taken:

1. I have created a module that should handle: open the file, read its content, process and return it.
2. This is already registered a Twig Extension so I already can write `{{ spit_the_content(<path>) }}`

Problem:

The `<path>`. Does Drupal provide Streams, or other functions to resolve paths like: `theme://misc/info.txt`? If not how does Drupal help me to get valid paths relativ to the active theme, a module or stuff alike?

```
{{ spit_the_content(path('theme://misc/info.txt')) }}
```

BTW: I am interested in both: urls (relative/absolute) and filesystem paths.

Comment: Extension stream wrappers are coming: https://www.drupal.org/node/1308152 until then it's a combo of base_path and directory (well covered in other posts I assume).

Comment: IF you were not using the custom stream wrappers, then you could use `file_url`, `url`, or `path` functions in twig defined in [TwigExtension](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Template!TwigExtension.php/class/TwigExtension/8.2.x) and listed on [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2486991).